# MySQL combine 3 queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get users from database based on 3 notes.

Where hobbies and countries are exactly as given

If number of users returned is less than 100 then go to next

Where hobbies are same but country is different

If number of total returned users is less than 100 then go to next
Where hobbies are different but country is same.

Here is my query that i wrote to get users whose hobbies and country are same.

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
JOIN user_opt ON users.id = user_opt.UserId 
WHERE user_opt.Disc=1 AND user_opt.country IN(".implode(',',$Countries).") AND user_opt.Hobbies REGEXP '".implode('|',$Interests)."'
```

Both `Countries` and `Interests` are arrays.
Now here is where i am stuck.I don't know how to check if number of returned rows is less than 100 or not.

Comment: Use `select count(*)` to get the number of rows that would be returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but i also need to return the users

Comment: `select ... limit 100` and see if you got 100 rows. If it's less, query more.

Comment: @user2722968 i know that way.But i want to combine it all in one qeury

Comment: You can't do all that in one query

Comment: Expanded in the answer on why you should `select ... limit 100` and re-run another query if you don't get enough rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate queries are perfectly fine: You give up consistency at the database layer, but you can fix it up at the application layer. The way to do it in one query is to

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS chunk, users.* 
      FROM users
      WHERE foo=bar
      UNION
      SELECT 2, users.*
      FROM users
      WHERE foo=bar AND foobar=barfoo
      UNION
      SELECT 3, users.*
      ...)
ORDER BY chunk
LIMIT 100
```

But this would most likely completely kill the query-planer and cause it to select all matching rows for all "subqueries" and limiting to the desired number of rows after sorting the entire resultset (only to find out that the first part of that union already had 100 rows). Spare the performance, fake it.